# Malloc and realloc of global variable in function

Tags: c, arrays, function, dynamic-arrays

I was trying to make reading of input from stdin with dynamic allocation in two different ways:

**1)** I read from stdin, malloc, realloc and write into array in main. Then when I printf those elements of array, everything is ok.

**2)** I declare global variable in main, then I throw it into function in which I read from stdin, malloc, realloc and write into that array. When I printf these elements in the function, it works fine but when I do that outside of function, it gives me Segmentation fault.

Can you check these codes and help me how to solve this problem?

**2)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void nacitaj( int *pocet_slov, char **slovnik ){

  char buffer[60];
  int size = 60;

  while( fgets( buffer, size, stdin ) != NULL ){
      *pocet_slov = *pocet_slov + 1;
      slovnik = (char**) realloc( slovnik, (*pocet_slov+1) * sizeof(char*) );
      slovnik[*pocet_slov-1] = (char*) malloc( strlen(buffer) * sizeof(char) );
      buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';
      strcpy( slovnik[*pocet_slov-1], buffer );
  }

  for( int i = 0; i < *pocet_slov; i ++ ){
      printf( "%d. %s\n", i+1, slovnik[i] );
  } 
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

int main(){
  char **slovnik = NULL;

  int pocet_slov = 0;

  int i;

  printf( "Zadavaj slova do slovniku:\n" );
  nacitaj( &pocet_slov, slovnik );

  for( i = 0; i < pocet_slov; i ++ ){
      printf( "%d. %s\n", i+1, slovnik[i] );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**1)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  char **slovnik = NULL;

  int pocet_slov = 0;

  char buffer[60];
  int size = 60;    
  int i;

  printf( "Zadavaj slova do slovniku:\n" );

  while( fgets( buffer, size, stdin ) != NULL ){
      pocet_slov ++;
      slovnik = (char**) realloc( slovnik, (pocet_slov+1) * sizeof(char*) );
      slovnik[pocet_slov-1] = (char*) malloc( strlen(buffer) * sizeof(char) );
      buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';
      strcpy( slovnik[pocet_slov-1], buffer );
  }

  for( i = 0; i < pocet_slov; i ++ ){
      printf( "%d. %s\n", i+1, slovnik[i] );
  } 

  return 0;
}
```

Example of input:

```
car
bird
pen
```

Comment: My input are words that are "imported" into vocabulary.. so for example:
car\nbird\npen

Comment: I mean specifically.  What is the exact input to program 2) that caused it to segfault?  And please update your question with this info.

Comment: for example those words... you can put there any word, press enter and then ctrl-D(EOF)

Comment: @alik33 please **update** your question and state **exactly** what your input is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be passing the address of `slovnik` to your `nacitaj` function.  Otherwise, updates to the variable in `nacitaj` are not visible in main.

Also, always remember to `free` any dynamically allocated memory.

```
void nacitaj( int *pocet_slov, char ***slovnik ){

  char buffer[60];
  int size = 60;

  while( fgets( buffer, size, stdin ) != NULL ){
      *pocet_slov = *pocet_slov + 1; 
      // dereference slovnik to update the variable in main
      // don't cast the return value of malloc or realloc
      *slovnik = realloc( *slovnik, (*pocet_slov+1) * sizeof(char*) );
      (*slovnik)[*pocet_slov-1] = (char*) malloc( strlen(buffer) * sizeof(char) );
      buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';
      strcpy( (*slovnik)[*pocet_slov-1], buffer );
  }

  for( int i = 0; i < *pocet_slov; i ++ ){
      printf( "%d. %s\n", i+1, (*slovnik)[i] );
  }
}

int main(){
  char **slovnik = NULL;

  int pocet_slov = 0;

  int i;

  printf( "Zadavaj slova do slovniku:\n" );
  // pass the address of slovnik 
  nacitaj( &pocet_slov, &slovnik );   

  for( i = 0; i < pocet_slov; i ++ ){
      printf( "%d. %s\n", i+1, slovnik[i] );
  }

  // free the allocated memory
  for( i = 0; i < pocet_slov; i ++ ){
      free(slovnik[i]);
  }
  free(slovnik);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, this was helpful (y).. by the way ye, I am aware of freeing the memory. I am just going to continue in this so I havent done it yet

Answer (score -1):

In the code number 2) you are not declaring a global variable. You should declare your global variable before main scope, example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int shared = 3;

void add(void){
     shared++;
}

int main(void){
     printf("%d", shared)// will print 3
     add();
     printf("%d", shared)// will print 4

     return 0;
}
```

This is just an example to achieve what you want, for education purpose only. You should be very carefully about global variables.

Comment: yes, much better, but your answer is actually not an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: LOL =) Have a nice day

Comment: While this demonstrates the use of global variables, it does not address OP's issue.